# Unit testing code which has logic around last login date of user

Tags: apex, unit-test, datetime

I need to write unit testing code which has logic around system field last login date of user.As per spring'16 release salesforce has added method for setting created date like below.

```
Test.setCreatedDate(recordId, createdDatetime)

Sets CreatedDate for a test-context sObject.
```

Is there anything similar method to set system field 'lastlogindate' of user.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. You can create users [see here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm) but not set last login.

In cases like this before I've refactored code to allow test data to be injected.